# Excluding Sold Out products from filter( SHOPIFY)

Tags: shopify, e-commerce, shopify-template

Need to exclude the variant product whenever the inventory is zero or not available

Now it showing all the unavailable variant product when I filter the product by size

Kindly suggest  me to fix this fix

I need to filter the product by its size

size is added throw Size tag

the condition also applied to filter current tags contains Size_

now need to exclude the unavailable variant from the product

Answer (score 0):

If you have filter all product by size you just need to put in right before the filter loop

```
{% if product.available %}
    Your liquid code here
{% endif}
```

[Variant.available](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/variant#variant-available)

Returns `true` if the variant is available to be purchased, or false if it is not. In order for a variant to be available, its `variant.inventory_quantity` must be greater than zero or `variant.inventory_policy` must be set to continue. A variant with no `variant.inventory_management` is also considered available.